# image object couldn't be saved

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, model-view-controller, word-cloud

I try to get an wordcloud image so I use two list words and frequencies and i get wordcloud but i work with MVC C#, actually i don't know how to send this controller to view,so i decided to save image object as a jpeg file, but save function get me error System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException generic error. This is my code :
            First i get the trends with twitter,and store them as words list has 29 value , second i make a list has 29 value :

```
        var trends = Trends.GetTrendsAt(1);
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        List<int> frequencies = new List<int>();
        foreach(var trend in trends.Trends)
        {
         if (g < 30)
         {
           words.Add(trend.Name);
           g++;
         }

        }
        for(int i = 29 ; i >= 1; i--)
        {
         frequencies.Add(i);   
        }


        var wc = new WordCloudGen(1000, 600);
        Bitmap y = new Bitmap(wc.Draw(words, frequencies));
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        y.Save("wordcloud.jpg", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
```

wc.Draw(words.frequencies) turns Image object actually, i try to convert it to bitmap so i thought i save it as jpeg file without problem.

I am new at engineering so i am really confused and i need your help, thanks.

Comment: Try to save it with y.Save("wordcloud.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); and check if you still get the same error.

Comment: @rs232 thanks but gives me same error unfortunately

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with a .Net console application and the program perfectly produced a nice .jpg file with a word cloud. You need to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @rs232 thank for the advice i added the code behind

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what makes an mcv example. I still can't copy that code, paste it into my Program.cs, launch it and see the outcome you describe. Could you please create a new console application, paste your code there (you probably would not have your Trends and stuff there, but you always can replace that all with a simple placeholder, like var words = new[] { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" }.ToList(); var frequencies = new[] { 1, 3, 7 }.ToList(); ). Do you still get the same error?

Comment: @rs232 thanks for your help. in console my codes work very vell. problem is i need a working word cloud in web . do you have any advice ? i get the trend topics and get a wordcloud in web. note : if you can answer in below as an answer i give you vote

Comment: So your code works as a part of console application, but the same code produce an exception when run as a part of MVC controller, right? Can you please post a detailed printout of the exception you've got? It it also possible that you have a folder permissions issue while trying to save your file to the current directory. You can try to specify a full path to your file with something like y.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/wordcloud.jpg"), myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters); and see if it works.

Comment: @rs232 i did  these changes to my code and it works now, i guess it is about path . 
  y.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\123.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);   but now in console image background was white, in mvc image background always black . have any idea ? (and in wordcloud nugget package there is no rule for background color)

Comment: I've made it into an answer so people having the same problem would see the solution immediately without digging through the comments. As for the background color, I don't really know. It is a kind of a separate question, it is not related to the original one. There might be something about WordCloud or it may be the image format peculiarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it possible that you have a folder permissions issue while trying to save your file to the current directory. You can try to specify a full path to your file with something like

```
y.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/wordcloud.jpg"), myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
```

and see if it works

Comment: @kamalaenderson also, dispose the image after saving; otherwise it may crash on a second save inside the same program run.